# akordeon.js how to set all container to "closed"

Tags: javascript, accordion

There is this akordeon.js script on Github
https://github.com/mshahbazsaleem/Akordeon/wiki

On default, the first container is always open and I just can not find a way to have all the containers closed. Can anyone help me with that?

UPDATE
I use this on a Magento shop within a CMS Page and the script entry looks like this at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.akordeon').akordeon({});
    });
```

});
    // ]]>

if I turn it into your version, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var max = jQuery('.akordeon-item').length;
jQuery('.akordeon').akordeon({ expandedItem:max});      
// ]]></script>
```

it breaks everything. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

That's a workaround:

> **expandedItem**: Item to be expanded by default, first item is expanded by
>   default

You have set the number higher than the number of containers.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var max = $('.akordeon-item').length;
      $('.akordeon').akordeon({ expandedItem:max});
  });
```

[Demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/VCT4D/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I tried many times but I failt. Can you pls read my update, maybe you know why.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem as yours but luckily I found the solution. When you call the function in the **head** tag, just type this line:

**expandedItem: 100;**

Your whole code will look like this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buttons').akordeon({expandedItem: 100});
    });
```